# One #define two values

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am writting the code in C and compiled in GCC. As the tittle says, how can I assign two values to the same `#define` statement. I don't mean to assign them like enum type or something, but in this way. Lets say I have a macro `SET_SOMETHING(num1,num2)`. How can I replace `num1,num2` with **ONE** `#define` statement named for example: `SOME_NUMBERS`. So when I will be "calling"(don't know if I am right saying calling) a macro it would look like this: `SET_SOMETHING(SOME_NUMBERS)`. I already tried the obvious way doing `#define SOME_NUMBERS 1,5` but just wont work for some reason, why? Doesnt the define just replaces the code?

If this would be possible, how would I then go to extract only the first or the second number from the define `SOME_NUMBERS` ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want [Variadic Macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)? How exactly would the 'multiple values' of the macro be used?

Comment: No. I just need predefined number of parameters replaced by one define statement. The macro would be used like I said above SET_SOMETHING(SOME_NUMBERS). So I would pass only one define, instead of two (for example) values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your macro parses `SOME_NUMBERS` it already has tried to separate the two arguments.
You'd have to have two macros in a row

```
#define INNER_MACRO(A, B) dosomething(A, B)
#define OUTER_MACRO(...) INNER_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__)
```